# Eclipse regex for $_GET['whatever']

Tags: regex, eclipse

I would like to find replace this in eclipse:

find: 
`$_GET['whatever']`

replace: 
`$this->input->get('whatever')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.  You have to make sure you have regular expressions turned on in the Find/Replace window.

```
Find: \$_GET\[('.*')\]
Replace: \$this->input->get($1)
```

It's not clear to me what your 'whatever' needs to be.  If it's only word characters you can replace the .* with \w.  You have to precede the dollar sign and the left and right brackets with a backslash (escape them) because they are special characters in the regex and if not escaped would be treated differently by the regex parser.

Good luck.